# What should I put in my SELECT * table where ___ statement when the data I'm basing it off from is on list view?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

What I'm trying to do is to display the Faculty member's schedule on lvSchedule  after clicking his name on lvFaculty.

```
Private Sub FillFaculty()
    Dim com As New OleDbCommand("Select FacultyName,FacultyID From qryFaculty", clsCon.con)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = com.ExecuteReader()
    lvFaculty.Items.Clear()
    While dr.Read()
        Dim lv As New ListViewItem(dr("FacultyID").ToString())
        lv.SubItems.Add(dr("FacultyName").ToString())
        lvFaculty.Items.AddRange(New ListViewItem() {lv})

        txtStatus.Text = lvFaculty.Items.Count.ToString() & " faculties found..."
    End While
    dr.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub DisplayFacultySchedule(ByVal Faculty As String)
    Dim dTimeIn As DateTime, dTimeOut As DateTime
    Dim randonGen As New Random()
    Dim com As New OleDbCommand("Select * From qrySubjectOfferring where FacultyID='" & Faculty & "'", clsCon.con)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = com.ExecuteReader()
    lvSchedule.Items.Clear()
    dataGridViewSchedule.Rows.Clear()
```

`("Select * From qrySubjectOfferring where FacultyID='" &`**`Faculty`**`& "'", clsCon.con)`

My main problem lies in **Faculty** since I know it's not what I should put there, but I have no idea what value to put instead of Faculty to make it base on what I selected from lvFaculty. I know it's not just Faculty... I've been tweaking it for a while, removing the WHERE statement does show the schedules, but it shows everything instead of how I want it to be.

Comment: Perhaps reference `lvFaculty.Column(1)` in the SQL construct because FacultyID is in second column. If you made FacultyID the first column in lvFaculty (and set ColumnWidths property so FacultyID is hidden), just reference `lvFaculty`. If FacultyID is a number type field, remove the apostrophe delimiters from the parameter.

Comment: Where exactly would I put lv.Faculty.Column(1)? and FacultyID is text

Comment: In place of `Faculty` as you requested. And it is `lvFaculty.Column(1)` without the extra period.

Comment: How do I reference lvFaculty.Column(1) as it would be the value of whatever I click on lvFaculty? and to answer your question earlier, I've hidden FacultyID on the listview

Comment: I don't know the exact syntax in vb.net to reference a specific column of listbox or combobox. What I showed is definitely correct for VBA and thought would be same. Have to let you research that. This would be moot if you made FacultyID the first column (hidden) of the listbox and set column 1 to be the bound column so the listbox will take that as its value (which in vb.net I think is actually the Text property as default).

Comment: Fair point. I appreciate it, pointing me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Having said that, if you currently have second column (FacultyID) set as the bound column, then simple reference to `lvFaculty` should actually work. I normally put the ID field as hidden first column and set it as the bound column, assuming you want to save the FacultyID as FK into record. However, I may be misunderstanding the control you are using for selection of faculty.

Comment: Actually, I have it set where FacultyID is the hidden first column

Comment: Okay, I was going by the SQL statement, didn't look at the following code that sets the ListView columns. So referencing `lvFaculty` does not work?

Comment: Sadly :( Trying to reference it with lvfaculty.click but it's not working either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your While loop use the tag property of the ListViewItem to store the ID.

```
Dim lv As New ListViewItem(dr("FacultyName"))
lv.Tag = dr("FacultyID")
lvFaculty.Items.Add(lv)
```

Then when an item in the list view is selected retrieve the ID thusly in your display faculty schedule Sub.

```
Dim myID As Integer = CInt(lvFaculty.SelectedItems(0).Tag)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. I wasn't able to store the ID properly, and this helped.